# Mystery margin or padding on list

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out where the padding is coming from the on the left of the list between each one:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/rAQYL/15/

As far as I know, the following code should stop this from happening. Can anyone please explain to me where this is coming from?

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hadn't closed the `a` in your `h1` for a start which was adding weird links between the items, but I believe the reason for the spacing is you haven't floated them and by default there is spacing between your li items when they have any variation of 'block' applied.

In the example below i've fixed the unclosed tag and added a float, hopefully this is what you were looking to do.

[See this fiddle of it working](http://jsfiddle.net/rAQYL/17/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1><a href="index.html">Admin</a></h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
            <li><a href="sites.html">Sites</a></li>
            <li><a href="feeds.html">Feeds</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">Content goes here</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#header {
    background-color:#1ABC9C;
}
#header a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#content {
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    padding: 20px;
}
#header h1, #header ul li, #header ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
#header ul li, #header h1 {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background: #16AD8F;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is from

```
display: inline-block;
```

applied on #header ul li.

you can use

```
float: left;
```

or give

```
margin-left: -3(4)px to each li.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list element are set to:

```
display:inline-block;
```

So there is space between them by default (it's treated like inline text, meaning that there is a space between each list).
In order to clear that space you can add this:

```
#header ul { font-size: 0; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rAQYL/20/)