# Padding not being correctly applied to header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to learn basic HTML and CSS. This is the code I have currently:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/vvDJ9/3/

There are two issues with the code:

1. Currently not only is there a large gap between the list items
2. The list in the header doesn't have the top padding correctly applied. It should sit in the middle of the header.

Here is the relevant bit of the code:

```
header a { padding: 15px 20px; background-color: #16AD8F; }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mystery margin or padding on list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019300/mystery-margin-or-padding-on-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `li`s are inline-blocks. You can, of course, redo the code and fix that using floats, for example... or get rid of the whitespace by joining `li`s together (`</li><li>...`, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/vvDJ9/6/), etc...

But there's a nice little hack to get rid of the space: set `font-size: 0;` to their parent `ul` element: http://jsfiddle.net/vvDJ9/5/

```
#header ul {font-size: 0;}
```

And to get the top padding correctly, just set your anchors to `display: block;`: http://jsfiddle.net/vvDJ9/9/

```
#header a {display: block;}
```

Comment: And if you want to remove the whitespace between the ul and h1 ("Admin" and the menu), remove the whitespace in the code: `</h1><ul>`: http://jsfiddle.net/vvDJ9/7/